# CryptoJS AES 256 ECB Decrypt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cryptojs

I already tried aes-ecb-js and now im trying cryptoJS if it can solve my problem. I already read a few topics and googled a lot but I am not able to decrypt a HEX String with AES ECB 256.

When using an online decoder it works just fine: 
[image]

I tried with the following code according to the documentation (https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers)

```
console.log('decrypt: ' + result)
        const dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(result, key)
        console.log(dec)
        console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(dec))
```

"key" in this case is a String which looks similar to this: `34AKDASFA12312ADSFKLSDK2`

The output is sadly undefined when trying to stringily the word array in var "dec"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with switching to the deprecated NPM Package [Crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto) which is now a built in functionality in NodeJS.

From there on it is a little messy (in my opinion) to decrypt an AES 256 ECB HEX String.

```
function decrypt(encodedString) {
  const crypto = require('crypto')
  const algorithm = 'aes-256-ecb'
  const dateKey = Buffer.from(
    '<YOUR_KEY>',
    'binary'
  )

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    algorithm,
    dateKey.toString('binary'),
    ''
  )
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
  let dec = decipher.update(encodedString, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8')
  return dec
}
```